# transition on fillStyle color

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I have a visualizer setup and it changes color every 7.5 seconds, problem is, it does it immediately, can you use .animate() on fillStyle? if not, is there any way to add a transition to fillStyle?

Comment: try transition-duration  -- https://jsfiddle.net/dhvbde8w/

Comment: I need to make a transition for the fillStyle property of a canvas, not a div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`fillStyle` does not have a method to automatically animate its transition.**

However, its fairly easy to create an animation loop that animates the transition.

What you do is draw your frenzied content twice per frame in animation loops occuring over 2.50 seconds:

- Draw with the starting color having an opacity that decreases over your 2.50 seconds.
- Draw with the ending color having an opacity that increases over your 2.50 seconds.

**Here's annotated example code and a Demo:**

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var duration=2.50;

// starting and ending colors
var rgbStart='#BC49FF';
var rgbEnd='#574FFF';
// calculate the # of frames that requestAnimationFrame can
// draw during the duration
var opacitySteps=parseInt(60*duration);
// set the current opacity step at its starting number (0)
var opacityStep=0;

// start the 2.5 second animation
requestAnimationFrame(animate);


function animate(time){

  // calculate the current opacity as a percentage
  //     of opacityStep/opacitySteps
  var opacity=100*(opacityStep/opacitySteps);
  if(opacityStep>=opacitySteps-1){ opacity=100; }

  // clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

  // draw with the starting color using a lessening opacity
  ctx.globalAlpha=(100-opacity)/100;
  ctx.fillStyle=rgbStart;
  ctx.fillRect(20,20,100,75);
  ctx.strokeRect(20,20,100,75);

  // draw with the ending color using a increasing opacity
  ctx.globalAlpha=(opacity)/100;
  ctx.fillStyle=rgbEnd;
  ctx.fillRect(20,20,100,75);
  ctx.strokeRect(20,20,100,75);

  // clean up, reset globalAlpha to it's default of 1.00
  ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;

  // return if all steps have been played
  if(++opacityStep>=opacitySteps){return;}

  // otherwise request another frame
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

$('#again').click(function(){
  opacityStep=0;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);    
})
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Transitioning a fillStyle over 2.50 seconds</h4>
<br><button id=again>Again</button>
<br><canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without requestAnimationFrame? because I had it before and it was just broken

Comment: Sure, you could use `setInterval` to call an animation frame at intervals over 2.50 seconds. When the 2.50 seconds has elapsed you can call `clearInterval` to stop the animation loop. Having said that, using `requestAnimationFrame` is the best programming practice (for performance and other reasons) and it would benefit your programming if you add it to your bag-of-tools ;-)  Good luck with your project!

Comment: I've used it 3 times in my website already, but the color were going by really quickly

Comment: I understand...`requestAnimationFrame` can be tricky to learn, but it has significant benefits once you've moved up the learning curve ;-). Keep in mind that `requestAnimationFrame` will automatically fire at approximately 60 frames per second, but it also gives you a current-time parameter that lets you draw your animation at specified elapsed times and just move on to the next frame if the elapsed time has not been reached. Here's an ok-but-not great post on how to get requestAnimationFrame under control: http://html5hub.com/request-animation-frame-for-better-performance/

Comment: Without jumping too far into your 500+ lines of code, I would say you would set your animation variables and begin a requestAnimationFrame at line 258. Another nice thing about requestAnimationFrame is that it runs asynchronously versus your other javascript code so you can set up the animation, fire it, and it will play to completion without further intervention on your part.

Comment: I've tried and the rectangle is being drawn with the opacity effect but not the bars, I've updated the website with the new version so that you can take a look

Comment: Time does not permit as outside yardwork calls me. BTW, what is the Da Vinci Race--sounds interesting!

Comment: it's a race that's happening in my school, and I had to make the website for my exams comming in 3 weeks

Comment: okay, I've tried again and I was able to have it do a transition when activating the mode but it stops making the transition afterward, weird